# Como pegar o tamanho do vídeo a partir do caminho?

Tags: javascript

Por favor segue a imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O tamanho do vídeo está dentro "context" (Caminho: context > Files
:FileList > 0:File > size)

Como pegar o tamanho do vídeo a partir do caminho em cima ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você quer pegar o tamanho do vídeo e está usando a mesma função de sua [outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/168779/como-mostrar-v%C3%ADdeo-selecionado-em-input-file), você pode obter pelo atributo `size` que é retornado em bytes. Então para converter em MB:

```
var tamanho = (this.files[0].size/1024)/1024; // Bytes > KB > MB
```

**JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ckLnyn5t/2/**

Comment: Valeu, agora entendi.

Comment: Porque 1024 bytes é 1 KB, e 1024 KB é 1 MB, assim por diante. [Veja](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilobyte)

Comment: @MatheusMiranda, testei com um vídeo menor e o retorno no tamanho foi compatível. Será que você ter olhada para o arquivo errado (diferente do uploaded) ao clicar com botão direito?

Comment: Agora deu certo, foi erro de escrever, valeu @LucasCosta